# Jquery Galleryview Autoplay

Tags: jquery, galleryview

I have two questions on JQuery Galleryview:

1. Is it possible to set autoplay to false?
2. Is there a way to have different width for filmstrip and the active/selected picture? For example: i want to have my film strip width as 600px but main picture to be 300px only

Here is my JQuery code currently:

```
        $('#myGallery').galleryView({
            panel_width: 600,
            panel_height: 500,
            frame_width: 100,
            frame_height: 70,
            show_overlays: true,

            filmstrip_position: 'top',
            autoPlay: false
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you read the manual? http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview The beta seems to support the autoplay option, the width can be configured, and you can always touch some CSS too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, set transition_interval to 0 and autoplay will go away. This can be done with the current version (not the Beta). Here's how:

```
    $('#myGallery').galleryView({
        panel_width: 600,
        panel_height: 500,
        frame_width: 100,
        frame_height: 70,
        show_overlays: true,
        filmstrip_position: 'top',
        transition_interval: 0
    });
```

I'm not sure about the second question, but I think what I'd do is try to give the strip a fixed width using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the page, you'll see autoplay = false will become available in version Beta 4.